# Connect remotely to the H2 Database using h2.jar

Tags: corda

I can't connect to my corda node h2 database remotely via the h2.jar user interface.

It says :
`Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: my-host:8001" [90067-194] 90067/90067`

On my VM the port is open :

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 8001
tcp    0    0 127.0.0.1:8001    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN    10098/java
```

Comment: Hi Remi, are you able to update this question with the full stack trace?

Comment: Also, are you able to telnet to the address and port? Are you sure there are no network devices between your local machine and your database host (e.g. proxy server, firewall)?

Answer (score 0):

As of Corda Enterprise 3.1, the node's H2 database is not exposed by default. This behaviour can be overridden by specifying the full network address (interface and port), using the new `h2Settings` syntax in the node configuration.

The configuration below will restrict the H2 service to run on `localhost`:

```
h2Settings {
    address: "localhost:12345"
}
```

If you want H2 to auto-select a port (mimicking the old `h2Port` behaviour), you can use:

```
h2Settings {
    address: "localhost:0"
}
```

If remote access is required, the address can be changed to `0.0.0.0`. However it is recommended to change the default username and password before doing so.

```
h2Settings {
    address: "0.0.0.0:12345"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solved also by adding a **.h2.server.properties** file in the home directory : 
and launching the java -jar h2.jar on the VM.

```js
1=H2|org.h2.Driver|jdbc\:h2\:tcp\://localhost\:8000/node|sa
webAllowOthers=true
webPort=8082
webSSL=false
```